# Parse 122 error upload

Tags: ios, parse-platform

If I save text without having any text in the field I get this error message in Parse.com: Update Failure - The operation couldn't be completed(Parse error 122.) If I press OK and then try to dismiss the view with Cancel(a button item) the app crashes. I think a valid file name at Parse.com has to contain at least 1 character. Maybe I can do do something to stop the user from saving when not enter text? Any ideas?

This my code:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    // Create PFObject with profile information
    PFUser *profile = [PFUser currentUser];
    [profile setObject:nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [profile setObject:titleTextField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [profile setObject:locationTextField.text forKey:@"location"];

    // Profile image
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImageView.image, 0.8);

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameTextField.text];

    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
    [profile setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profileimageFile"];

    // Show progress
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Updating";
    [hud show:YES];

    // Upload profile to Parse

    if(nameTextField.text.length==0 && titleTextField.text.length==0 && locationTextField.text.length==0)

    [hud hide:YES];

    [profile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile Information" message:@"Fill in atleast one field" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];

                [hud hide:YES];
            }
            else {
            // Show success message
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Successfully updated profile" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

            [hud hide:YES];

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:self];
        }
    }];
}


- (IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1

Test if your one letter theory is true.  Change:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameTextField.text];
```

To:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%@", nameTextField.text];
```

## 2

Or just avoid it if it's blank.  So this:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameTextField.text];

PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
[profile setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profileimageFile"];
```

Becomes:

```
if (nameTextField.text) {
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameTextField.text];

    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
    [profile setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profileimageFile"];
}
```

## 3

Also, what is this:

```
if(nameTextField.text.length==0 && titleTextField.text.length==0 && locationTextField.text.length==0)
```

It's doesn't appear to be connected to anything?

## 4

You call this twice in quick succession, and then again right after the file saves. Is there something in the method that makes the repetitive calls necessary?

```
[hud hide:YES];
```

## 5

Your if statement doesn't appear to be connected to anything:

```
if(nameTextField.text.length==0 && titleTextField.text.length==0 && locationTextField.text.length==0)
```

I'm assuming you want:

```
if(nameTextField.text.length==0 && titleTextField.text.length==0 && locationTextField.text.length==0) {

    [hud hide:YES];

    [profile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile Information" message:@"Fill in atleast one field" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];

            [hud hide:YES];
        }
        else {
            // Show success message
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Successfully updated profile" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

            [hud hide:YES];

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:self];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get this error still: Error: Bad file name: (Code: 122, Version: 1.2.18) 

About number 3: I'm trying to make sure that the user fill in atleast one field. But I haven't got that to work jet :(

About number 4: You so right I took it away

Comment: Have you tried it with a static filename to see if that's really the problem? What happens if you change the filename to "testName" just to see if we can narrow the problem down.

Comment: It works if I put in text. The only problem is when I try to save and the field is empty. This is what the parse doc says:  "InvalidFileName, 122 - Error code indicating that an invalid filename was used for ParseFile. A valid file name contains only a-zA-Z0-9_. characters and is between 1 and 128 characters." So I guess I maybe need to get this to work if(nameTextField.text.length==0 && titleTextField.text.length==0 && locationTextField.text.length==0) so that you can't save if its empty. But I can't get it to work. Feels like self.saveButton.enabled or could work? But I cant get it to work

Comment: Well if your code matches your question, your if statement doesn't appear to apply to anything.  It's just there for some reason.

Comment: Thanks man! Do you now how to fix it? Been trying for days :(

Comment: Put all the code you want in brackets.  if (someCondition) {// code in here}

Comment: I amended my answer to show you what I think you mean.